# Cleanup usage in useEffect in React need or not need?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the below usage for the `useEffect` hook, I am detecting the window width, then if the window is a certain width the function sets the state, but would I need to cleanup the `useEffect` in this case or would it need no cleanup? I know in the context of an API you could unsubscribe to the API in the return, So the return will run when the component un mounts

Is it correct in setting the `windowWidth` again or is it better to remove the return from the `useEffect` hook totally?

```js
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = React.useState<number>(0);
const [column, setColumn] = React.useState<number>(10);

const calcWindow = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (windowWidth < 768) {
    setColumn(() => 5);
  } else {
    setColumn(() => 10);
  }
}, [windowWidth]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  calcWindow();
  return () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth); // is this needed or is this correct?
  };
}, [calcWindow, windowWidth]);
```

Comment: What's the point of setting component state on unmount?

Comment: IN other words no need for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned function here is unnecessary. When the component is about
to unmount, you shouldn't be setting the state since that state is just going to go away. During a re-render, the cleanup function will run and set window width, but the value will be overridden in the effect immediately from the `setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);` call.